# self join on huge table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have below table:

**table1:**

```
dateField   |   curStatus   |   prevStatus   |   statusChangeDate

2015-01-15  |      0        |      27        |   2015-01-15
2015-01-16  |      27       |      0         |   2015-01-16
2015-01-17  |      0        |      27        |   2015-01-17
2015-01-18  |      27       |      0         |   2015-01-18
```

I want ONLY those records, of which, the **curStatus** was **0** and **prevStatus** was **27** at the first place, and **WITHIN 2 DAYS**, **curStatus** changed **from 0 to 27** and **prevStatus from 27 to 0**.

The table contains huge data.

I have tried below query :

```
SELECT A.dateField, B.dateField, A.curStatus, B.curStatus, A.prevStatus, B.prevStatus 
FROM table1 A, table1 B
WHERE A.curStatus = 27 and A.prevStatus = 0
AND B.curStatus = 0 AND B.prevStatus = 27 AND CONVERT(DATE,B.statusChangeDate) <= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(d, -2, GETDATE()))
```

**but it gives me Cartesian product:**

Can anyone please help me with the query?
Database used is SQL Server

Comment: Of course it gives you a cartesian product. You are not joining the tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : A probable solution would be of Great help.

Comment: I don't get why you want to join tables

Comment: Do you have any ID of this record?

Comment: It would help if you could include some data that wouldn't be included in the results. It's not clear what data you are trying to return. Very confused about the requirement for them changing. And 2 days from current date? Or that they changed within 2 days or each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cross apply:

```
SELECT 
  A.dateField, B.dateField, A.curStatus, B.curStatus, A.prevStatus, B.prevStatus 
FROM 
  table1 A
CROSS APPLY
(
-- consider using
--  SELECT top 1 dateField, curStatus, prevStatus 
-- if you only want 1 row for each match
SELECT dateField, curStatus, prevStatus 
FROM table1
WHERE 
  dateField BETWEEN a.dateField and dateadd(d, 2, a.dateField) AND 
  curStatus = 0 and prevStatus = 27
-- in case you just want 1 row
-- ORDER BY datefield --(or whatever you want to order by)
) B
WHERE A.curStatus = 27 and A.prevStatus = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only 2 types: 0 and 27 and you need to get the updated records from last two days (from current date) you can simple use below code. But if you have more types you will need something that will identify the row for exxample the primary key.

```
create table st27 

(

datafield datetime,

curstatus int,

prevstatus int,

statuschangedate datetime

)

insert into st27 VALUES ('2015-01-15'  ,      0       ,     27,   '2015-01-15')
insert into st27 VALUES ('2015-01-16'  ,      27      ,      0         ,   '2015-01-16')

insert into st27 VALUES ('2015-01-17'  ,      0        ,      27        ,   '2015-01-17')

insert into st27 VALUES ('2015-01-18'  ,      27       ,      0         ,   '2015-01-18')


select *,datediff(d,statuschangedate, getdate())  from st27 where curstatus = 27 and prevstatus = 0  and datediff(d,statuschangedate, getdate()) <= 2
```

Gives one record:
    2015-01-18 00:00:00.000 27  0   2015-01-18 00:00:00.000 1